# Cannot find column 0. error in vb.net while adding values to the datarow

Tags: string, datatable, vb.net-2010, datarow

having datatable.while adding values to that row am getting error. Using for loop each and every time i add a new value to that datarow in the datatable.

```
my code
=======
dt3 = ds1.Tables(0)
                For Each q In dt3.Rows
                    chkphone = q("PHONE").ToString
                    chkdphone = Regex.Replace(chkphone, "[^\d]", "")

                    'MessageBox.Show(chkdphone)


                    If (chkdphone.Length = 10) Then
                        Dim NTN As DataRow = dt4.NewRow
                        NTN(0) = chkdphone.ToString
                        dt4.Rows.Add(NTN)

                    ElseIf (chkdphone.Length >= 10) Then
                        rsltstring = chkdphone.Substring(chkdphone.Length - 10, 10)

                        Dim NTN1 As DataRow = dt4.NewRow
                        NTN1(0) = rsltstring.ToString
                        dt4.Rows.Add(NTN1)
                    End If
                Next

when i debug the code in first itself am getting error in the line NTN(0) = chkdphone.ToString



error :  could not find column 0
```

Comment: What is "Dt4"? If you havent initialized all the columns settings there will be none

Comment: dt4 is a datatable. initialized in global

Comment: and have you setup the columns in it?

Comment: thanks for ur comment.i forgot to initialize the datacolumn for dt4.

Comment: ya i did.answer came .very thanks for ur reply